# "ImportError: cannot import name connect" when trying to import Stem

Tags: python, configuration, tor, stem

I am trying to go through Stem's tutorial for Python, using Ubuntu 14.04. After using `sudo apt-get install python-stem` and installing Stem, I found myself not knowing how to use it.

I tried to run simple code below, which I got from https://stem.torproject.org/api/connection.html#stem.connection.connect

```
import sys

from stem.connection import connect

if __name__ == '__main__':
  controller = connect()

  if not controller:
    sys.exit(1)  # unable to get a connection

  print 'Tor is running version %s' % controller.get_version()
  controller.close()
```

but I get this error:

```
~/example$ python controller.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 3, in <module>
    from stem.connection import connect
ImportError: cannot import name connect
```

Seems like Python cannot find the Stem code.
My question is how to fix this? Do I need to do something with installed Stem file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it running by using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install stem
```

Pip is the Python package manager which will install the modules to the correct paths for Python.

Comment: when running the first command, lot of 404 Not Found, so "sudo: pip: command not found" for second command

Comment: got pip installed by advise here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/561377/pip-wont-run-throws-errors-instead

Comment: If you get lots of 404's using apt-get install, run `sudo apt-get update` first to update your package lists.